# Why is this not enough for preventing double submission of form?

Tags: javascript, forms

The solution I'm always using is the following:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

However, when I look at other questions regarding this people are suggesting overly complicated solutions which make me think the above is not sufficient.

What drawbacks does this have if you only want to prevent people from accidentally submit the form twice?

Comment: I could type `$("form").submit()` in the console and your form gets submited. (and even an overlay wouldn't prevent me from doing this) so it's much more compilcated.

Comment: What others are suggesting? I dont see any issues. to prevent F5 issue try using [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for accidental double submission , but most of the time, this overly complicated method is implemented against hackers and other users who try to circumvent your safety, e.g those who try to spam the site by registering hundreds of users by refreshing the page.

Thats why many forms use a token, generated by the server, which is valid for only one submission, and one ip gets only one token for example.

Answer (score 0):

The only *real* way you can prevent double submission is to check for it on the server side.

Client side code is very unreliable and can be changed ***very easily*** by the client.